# i wrote this code to find the largest and smallest (int)number but it does not work

Tags: python, max, min

I wrote this code to get an input of several int numbers and write the smallest and largest of them but the code does not work.

```
numbers=[]    
num=input('enter your number')    
Int_num=int(num)    
Int_num.append(numbers)    
print('maximum number is:',max(numbers))    
print('minimum number is:',min(numbers))
```

Comment: `Int_num.append(numbers)` -> `numbers.append(Int_num)`

Comment: you append numbers which is a empty list

Comment: you only get one input and then append it to a list.
so your list will have only one item and the results of max and min will be that number.
more than that you should replace the appending code with `numbers.append(Int_num)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! "Does not work" is insufficient description of your problem. What does it actually do? Do you get an error? Or does it simply print the wrong value? Or is it something else? Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask],
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). You will also find this helpful: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: please search about https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/
to get familiar with PEP8

Comment: @A.Najafi No, nothing is appended "_to a list_".

Comment: @OneCricketeer I know! His/Her intention is appending some numbers and getting the max or min of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get a sequence of numbers:

```
numbers = []
while True:
  number = input('Enter a number or enter q to exit: ')
  if number == 'q':
      break
  else:  
      numbers.append(int(number))

print(f'Max: {max(numbers)}, Min: {min(numbers)}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Int_num.append(numbers)` with `numbers.append(Int_num.append)`

To get multiple numbers you can try:

```py
numbers = []
last_number = input('Enter a number: ')
while last_number:
  numbers.append(int(last_number))

print(f'Max: {max(numbers)}, Min: {min(numbers)}')
```

Comment: This answer is wrong, your condition for while loop is always True and this would cause an infinite loop. You have to edit the anwer.

Comment: Empty string is evaluated to `False` so you exit the loop when you simply press Enter without typing anything else. Perhaps on some systems you might need to add `.strip()`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to append a list to a integer, it should be `numbers.append(Int_num)`, so you will append the number `Int_num` to the list `numbers`.

Comment: If you want to enter a sequence of numbers, you need to turn each number to integer separately and then append to the array

Comment: Try to use this if you want a sequence of integer numbers, it transforms every number in the input into integers numbers, and store the result into the `numbers` list:

    num=input('enter your number')(line break)
    numbers = [int(x) for x in num.split()]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
numbers=[]       
num=input('enter your number')

while num != "":
    Int_num=int(num)    
    numbers.append(Int_num)    
    num=input('enter your number') 

print('maximum number is:',max(numbers))    
print('minimum number is:',min(numbers))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is line
Int_num.append(numbers)
it should be
numbers.append(Int_num)

Also if you put a while(True): around all but the first line you can add lots of numbers to the list (use ctrl+c to stop the program, if it's running in cmd or powershell)

Comment: If you use ctrl+C to stop the program, how do you get it to print the max and min?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Alex said "around all but the first line".